# PHP header redirect strange issue

Tags: php

I'm using PHP header re-directs to push my users through my PHP-HTML site, however I'm getting an unusual issue when attempting to do this.

The content displayed on-screen is **not** blank, but instead is the re-directed URL, however the URL bar still seems to show the old URL prior to re-directing.

There are no `echo "";` statements, `print_r();` statements or `var_dump();` statements that could be causing this, nor is there any wild HTML or white-spaces (I've checked thrice, all HTML is encased in `<<<HTML [htmlhere] HTML;` and white-spaces have been eliminated using "Find & Replace")

I've also attempted to use `exit();` after my header code to no assistance. Could anyone let me know if I'm being silly here?

**Code**

```
<?PHP
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
  session_start();
}
function getPage($link)
{
  $contents="";
  $cSession=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
  curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
  curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
  $contents.=curl_exec($cSession);

  if(preg_match('#HTTP/1.1(.*)#',$contents,$t))
  {
    $code=trim($t[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    $code="";
  }

  if($code=="301 Moved Permanently")
  {
    if(preg_match('#Location:(.*)#',$contents,$r))
    {
      $l=trim($r[1]);
    }

    $contents="";
    $handler=fopen($l,"r");

    while(!feof($handler))
    {
      $contents.=fread($handler,1024);
    }

    fclose($handler);
  }
  else if($code=="200 OK")
  {
    $contents=curl_exec($cSession);
  }
  else
  {
    $contents="";
  }
  curl_close($cSession);

return $contents;
}

function checkPage($content)
{
  $links=array();
  $textLen=strlen($content);
  if($textLen>10)
  {
    $startPos=0;
    $valid=true;

    while($valid)
    {
      $spos=strpos($content,'<a',$startPos);
      if($spos<$startPos)
      {
        $valid=false;
      }
      else if($spos===FALSE)
      {
        $valid=false;
      }
      else
      {
        $spos=strpos($content,'href',$spos);
        $spos=strpos($content,'"',$spos)+1;
        $epos=strpos($content,'"',$spos);
        $startPos=$epos;
        $link=substr($content,$spos,$epos-$spos);
        if(strpos($link,"http://")!==false)
        {
          $link=rtrim($link,'/');
          $links[]=$link;
        }
        else if(strpos($link,"https://")!==false)
        {
          $link=rtrim($link,'/');
          $links[]=$link;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $links;
}

function checkArray($array,$url)
{
  $new_array=array();
  $update=array();

  foreach($array as $child)
  {
    if(strpos($child,$url)===FALSE)
    {
      $child="";
    }
    else
    {
      if($child===$url)
      {
        $child="";
      }
      $new_array[]=$child;
    }
  }

  $new_array=array_unique($new_array);
  $new_array=array_filter($new_array);

  return $new_array;
}

$v_url_to_check="";
$v_api="";

if(isset($_POST["URL"])&&isset($_POST["Feedback"]))
{
  $v_url_to_check=filter_var($_POST["URL"],FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
  $v_api=filter_var($_POST["Feedback"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
else if(isset($_POST["URL"])&&!isset($_POST["Feedback"]))
{
  $v_url_to_check=filter_var($_POST["URL"],FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
  $v_api="";
}
else
{
  $_SESSION["Message"]="BadData";
  header("Location:".$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);
  exit;
}

if(strpos($v_url_to_check,".")===FALSE)//
{   
  $_SESSION["Message"]="Failed";
  header("Location:".$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);
  exit;
}
else
{
  $a_content=checkPage(getPage($v_url_to_check));
  $new_array=checkArray($a_content,$v_url_to_check);

  $count=0;
  foreach($new_array as $child)
  {
    $count++;
  }
  $i=0;
  foreach($new_array as $childs)
  {
    $update["Child$i"]=$childs;
    $i++;
  }

  if($count!=0)
  {
    $_SESSION["Message"]="Success";
    $_SESSION["Links"]=$count;
    $_SESSION["ReturnedArray"]=$update;
    $_SESSION["RequestedURL"]=$v_url_to_check;
    $_SESSION["FeedbackValue"]=$v_api;

    header('Location:'.$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);
    exit;
  }

  else
  {
    $_SESSION["Message"]="Failed";

    header("Location:".$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

`$_SESSION['loc']` is being set in the main code (index.php) but, as that has no issue with re-directing, I'm not including it.

**EDIT**: `header("Location: ".$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);` (using a space after the colon) did not make a difference in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Wow, so I was totally wrong! It wasn't the re-directing that was the issue, it was the main index page (which re-directed to the form PHP code perfectly well)

In the main index page I had the following code that, when taken out resolved the problem:

**CODE**

```
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<SCRIPT src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

It seems including jquery was the thing that killed it.

Not sure exactly how it did this, but removing this takes away some functionality. I need it for a HTML form input range slider that changes values on the fly. If anyone wants to have a look and tell me in the comments how jquery could cause PHP header location information to crash, I'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using space after location like this may be error is due to space,

```
header("Location: ".$_SESSION['loc'],true,301);
```

Also Visit this Link for header with permanent or temporary redirect.
[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#78470)